# HTML password pattern validation

Tags: html, validation

Below is the the requirement I have to apply to Login page.

To enter the password of the customer.

The text “Enter the password” should be displayed by default in the text box.

At present when the password is entered the text is visible.  Make the necessary changes so that the text entered for password  is masked.

Password can contain alphabets, numbers and underscore. It should  contain a minimum of 8 and a maximum of 15 characters.

this is my code below

```html
Password<input type="password" name="password" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]{8,15}" placeholder="Enter the password" minlength=8 maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" required><br>
```

But when i execute it.it failed.and shows

> Fail 1 - Check the HTML component 'input' field with the name 'password' and it must be used with correct pattern which is specified in the problem description.

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you please paste your Javascript code? If you're validating the form using Javascript

Comment: no I am just using html5. no javascript.

Comment: What environment or tool are you executing this code in such that it gives you this "fail" error message?

Answer (score 2):

Validation is correct for minimum 8 character and maximum 15 character.
i.e  [a-zA-Z0-9_]{8,15}
Also, there is no need to write minlength=8 maxlength="15"